# Delete/backspace not working in RadDatePicker

Tags: javascript, telerik, asp.net-4.0

I am using a RadDatePicker, but the problem is that backspace/delete are not working. So if once a user selects a date there is no way he can deselect it.

Comment: Try to post the code you have used.

Comment: <lpsfs:SysXDatePicker runat="server" ID="dpLastBackgroundCheckedDate" DateInput-ReadOnly="true"
                                    DateInput-DateFormat="MM-dd-yyyy" Width="99%">
                                    <ClientEvents OnPopupClosing="FocusOnPopUpButton" />
                                    <Calendar ID="calLastBackgroundCheckedDat" runat="server" EnableKeyboardNavigation="true"
                                        CausesValidation="false">

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are not having the **DateInput-Enabled** & **EnableTyping** properties as **false**.

Try to change it as:

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker DateInput-Enabled="true" EnableTyping="true" runat="server" />
```

Comment: if i do the above delete starts working,but then a user can also add alphabets and char. to the controls.

Comment: But while moving the focus out of the box, it will show the warning image inside the box